# Which format to print the number with leading spaces?

Tags: java, format-specifiers

Input:

```
3
100
12
```

Output:

```
      003
      100
      012
```

I need to print the numbers after 10 spaces and then print the number using format specifier all starting from 11th position as shown. I tried 
`%013d` format specifier, but the output contains trailing zeroes, but I need spaces.

Comment: 10 spaces always?... seems pretty easy to print 10 spaces always... just print 10 spaces before printing the number! Unless I missed something

Comment: could you show your code?

Comment: Change 13 to 3 and add 10 spaces in front of %.

Comment: output required:  rahul                         100 ;
actually there is a string before the integer,i need this output, but if spaces are added before integer, the required output may change depending on the string length.

Comment: @AmpatiHareesh what you commented is very different to what you initially asked. Please edit the question and add some examples of what you *actually* need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you store your number as an `int x`, then just use:

```
System.out.format("          %03d", x);
```

If you have a `String text = "test";` that you wish to include in the first 10 chars before the number (assuming that its length is less than 10), then you can do the following:

```
System.out.format("%10s%03d", text, x);
```

This will print:

```
      test003
```

If you want `text` to appear on the beginning of the string, then use:

```
System.out.format("%-10s%03d", text, x);
```

This will print:

```
test      003
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the formatting twice like this:

```
System.out.format("%13s", String.format("%03d", x));
```

So first you format the number to 0-padded string, then format this string to space-padded string.